# Stuck on Ubuntu (Wayland) WM

Tags: login, login-screen, wayland

Fairly simple problem, but I am at a loss re how to debug or fix the issue.

I switched to Ubuntu (Wayland). Everything kinda works fine, but there are slight issues with a few programs, so logged out, clicked the gear icon to log back in using the default shell. And it just loops me back to login screen. I try a second time, and the machine locks. Tried logging in with compiz, exactly the same issue. The *only* option I can use is Wayland, it's been like this for the last month or so as I searched for and tried various fixes.

I've searched for similar issues on here, on Ubuntu/Linux forums and all solutions to similar issues are not fixing the issue. I *really* do not want to reinstall; it's a dev machine that I've quite carefully set up, and if at all possible I want to avoid doing that for a second time.

Edit: Ubuntu version is stock 18.04

Comment: Why is the only option that you can use is Wayland. Wayland isn't ready for prime time. Login loops can be caused by incorrect settings of two .*thority* files in your home directory. What version Ubuntu are you working with?

Comment: @heynnema regarding why the only option that works is Wayland — that's literally what my question is, if I knew then I wouldn't have the issue. The version is 18.04. The default login screen has two options for WM: Ubuntu, and Ubuntu (Wayland), and once the latter was selected, other options triggered the login loop. I understand what Wayland is, the reason I selected it in the first place was to check if it was functional.

Comment: @heynnema I have one *thority file, .ICEauthority, (which shouldn't be relevant?). I was expecting an Xauthority dotfile for some reason, but there isn't one present.

Comment: Does it meet any of the criteria in my answer? Otherwise, you may have something else going on... Nvidia drivers are notorious.

Comment: When is this bullsh*t ever going to stop  It’s time you work together. We all want the same… Ubuntu is based on Debian, I got the same issue with an Ubuntu install 2 months ago

Answer (score 1):

If you've been starting graphic applications from the terminal using `sudo`, that's what probably caused your problem. Always use `sudo -H`.

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type:

  - `sudo mount -o remount,rw /` # remount the disk as rw
  - `cd /home/your_username` # change directory
  - `ls -al .*thority*` # list some files

You should see something like this...

```
-rw------- 1 your_username your_username 407910 Nov  2 08:56 .ICEauthority
-rw------- 1 your_username your_username     58 Jun 23  2017 .Xauthority
```

If it DOES NOT show `-rw-------` then...

- `sudo chmod 600 .*thority*` # change file protection

If it DOES SHOW `root root` then...

- `sudo chown your_username:your_username .*thority*` # change file ownership
- `reboot` # reboot the computer

Reboot and see if you can log in.

**Update #1:**

We created a new "Guest" account, and it logs in fine. That confirms that there's something in the original account's home folder that's causing the login loop.

Comment: Ach, this is a good set of instructions, and I have been starting one specific application using the terminal, and there is a good chance that I've accidentally started it with `sudo` (thank you for the advice on that, just read up on the issues). But it's still not working. For starters, I don't have an Xauthority file, but notwithstanding that, I have a horrible suspicion that the root cause _is_ Nvidia drivers: I have an MX150 card, and I installed the proprietary drivers straightaway when I switched the laptop to Ubuntu because the system wasn't picking the card up. Just purging them now

Comment: @DanCouper please keep me posted. If it's working under Wayland, create a new user called... Guest. Log out. Log into Guest using Ubuntu (not Wayland), and see if the login loop occurs like it does on your normal account. This will eliminate 1/2 of potential software problems. Report back.

Comment: aha! Yes, this allows me to log in immediately. So with that in mind, I am assuming a rogue configuration in my home folder

Comment: Also @heynnema this is, afaics, not Nvidia driver related: all the drivers and related bumph was purged, with no change to behaviour.

Comment: Confirmed. The problem is in your normal account's home folder. I'd check the .bash* files, and the .config. folder. Backup .config to .config.BAK or .config.zip, then rename .config to .config.HOLD, then try to log in again.

Comment: I have this problem but the files are not present... On a reboot it seems I can login but I just got a black screen. (Debian 11)

Comment: @jaques-sam We don't support Debian here. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/